# MovieClip(root) Not working. How to access root variable from movieclip? Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok Ive got a simple flash file, since im trying to accomplish accessing a variable from the main stage inside a movie clip. All the things Ive found from google point to MovieClip(root). But its not working for me.

On the main timeline:

```
var MyName:String;
MyName = "kenny";
```

Then I have a movieclip called MyBox, its code:

```
trace(MovieClip(root).MyName);
```

And I get this error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@2d2df089 to flash.display.MovieClip.
    at MyBox/sendpmtext()

I have also tried MovieClip(parent), MovieClip(parent.parent), MovieClip(stage), MovieClip(this.stage) and no luck. Any help please?

Comment: That produces Property MyName not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value. GRRR Am I retarded???

Comment: parent["MyName"] gave the same error. :( I dont know how to use a document class file. Am I missing a GLOBAL keyword perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do

```
parent["MyName"];
```

OR, a proper casting of the main timeline (in your context, the parent is of type MainTimeline):

```
MainTimeline(parent).MyName;
```

Parent is always a `DisplayObjectContainer`, which has no special properties you create. If you create custom properties, then you need to cast to the class that has those custom properties before you'll be able to access them by name.  (the compiler otherwise doesn't know they exist, and gives you that error).

`root` refers to the topmost stage of your swf.  Your main timeline is actually a child of stage, so vars/objects/methods on the main timeline are not a part of `stage`

---

If your using `stage.addChild(MyBox)`, then `stage` is the parent, and not the main timeline.  If for some reason you need to have stage as the parent, then you'd have to keep a reference to the mainTimeline somewhere you can access.  You could create a var to do this in your MyBox timeline.

```
var mainTimeline:MainTimeline;
```

Then in the main timeline code, do this:

```
MyBox.mainTimeline = this;
```

Then you can access your var within MyBox by doing `mainTimeline.MyName;`

Comment: MainTimeline(parent).MyName; gives error Symbol 'MyBox', Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 15 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method MainTimeline. Does it matter that the movieclip MyBox was added via the addChild()? stage.addChild to be precise

Comment: yes, it does.   because now `stage` is the parent, and not the main timeline.  use addChild instead of stage.addChild

Answer (score 0):

`Stage` is `DisplayObject`, but not `MovieClip`. Try to use coercion

```
DisplayObject(stage)
```

or

```
DisplayObjectContainer(stage)
```

and to access custom properties:

```
DisplayObject(this)["MyName"]
```

Comment: That gives me these errors: Access of possibly undefined property MyName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject. and Access of possibly undefined property MyName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: DisplayObject(stage)["MyName"] gives Property MyName not found on flash.display.Stage and there is no default value.

Comment: My mistake, do you want to access movieclips on stage?

Comment: Thank you for helping me by the way. I dont understand why Im getting these errors. Ive got an AS3 file in Flash CS5.

Comment: MyName isn't in the scope of the stage,  that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: I dont believe so. I have a layer on the main timeline (entire project is just 1 frame) and I right click->actions. Thats where I declared the variable and set its value to "kenny". I then created a movieclip and am trying to access that variable from INSIDE the movieclip MyBox.