# Actionscript 3, how do I make a menu appear by clicking a button, on the same frame?

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have a button called manpb. When I click manpb, I want a menu to appear. The menu is a picture, but I can convert it into an object if this helps.
The best I can do is: Make a second frame with the menu, and insert the code inside the man_pb function:

```
    gotoAndStop(2);
```

My problem is that I want the menu to appear on the same frame; then the menu will have buttons of his own. Any idea what to type inside the function below?

```
    manpb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, man_pb);
    function man_pb(event:MouseEvent):void{ 

    }
```

A big thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most intuitive solution might be to have your menu inside a MovieClip on the same frame. The menu buttons can also be placed within that menu MovieClip.

Simply convert your menu picture to a MovieClip (right-click, convert to MovieClip). Make sure that you select the MovieClip, and in the Properties panel give it an Instance Name, like `menuMC` or anything you want.

There are then a couple ways that you could handle making the menu appear only when you click the button.

1- Set the MovieClip's opacity to 0 by default, and then include this in your button function:

```
menuMC.alpha = 1;
```

thereby changing the MovieClip to fully opaque.

2- Make the MovieClip comprised of two frames, one empty frame that has a `stop();` action, and one frame that contains your menu image and buttons. Then the button code would be:

```
menuMC.gotoAndStop(2);
```

3- Load the MovieClip dynamically from your library. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353908/how-to-add-a-movieclip-from-the-library-to-the-stage-programmatically) for more information. **edit:** This is the approach that @DodgerThud is referring too, and is the more advanced but more comprehensive approach.

Comment: I didn't know about the opacity, thank you! Could come in handy! I still don't want to use two frames though. I want everything done in the same frame, because I have 4 menus and 8 options per menu which influence my frame in different manners. I cannot do 1,048,576 frames to cover all possibilities. The menu has to appear within the same frame... Thank you for your reply though! I appreciate it!

Comment: Definitely, glad that somewhat helped! If you use @DodgerThud's or my approach then you should be able to nest menu options inside of others. The 'second' frame I refer to in my answer is actually contained 'within' the first frame. With a MovieClip, you can have timelines inside of timelines, essentially.

Comment: Right! Second frame is within the object, awesome! I think this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: But if my menu is a symbol, then can I edit variables in the symbol (in as3); variables that were defined and initialized in the root?

Comment: @user3105028 The variables are indeed still accessible. AS3 allows you to do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589904/moviecliproot-not-working-how-to-access-root-variable-from-movieclip-flash-a

Answer (score 0):

Use your Menu as an Object and add it to the MovieClip you want.

```
var menu:Menu = new Menu();//This is your Menu Symbol in your Library, you need to create one before you can use it
var manpb;//you could do the same thing for button, so you only need one symbol that has uses different labels

manpb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, man_pb);

function man_pb(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(contains(menu)){//checking if "menu" already exists
        removeChild(menu);//remove it from the displaylist
     }else{
        addChild(menu);//add it to the displaylist
    }
}
```

In the Listener function you check if your current MovieClip (this should NOT be Button) already has a child that is menu. If it does, it removes the menu, otherwise, it will add the menu.

Don't forget to export your Menu for ActionScript.

Comment: I believe this is the correct way to do it. Unfortunately, I do not understand what you mean by "export menu for actionscript". I only know how to work in a single file. Can you send me a link with some information on what you mean?

Comment: @user3105028 sure. your Menu asset should be a symbol in your library (usually on the lower right in flash, i believe). Right click your asset and click on 'properties', then on the advanced arrow. After that just click the checkbox for 'Export to Action Script' and confirm. This will ensure that you can this symbol in your code, and that you can create as many times you want, and remove it. [see here for more information](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_export_for_as.html)

Comment: But if my menu is a symbol, then can I edit variables in the symbol (in as3); variables that were defined and initialized in the root?