# How to make a movieClip move independent of the stage if added on it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

In my flash-made game, if my character jump on top of an enemy movieclip it spawns 3 minions from another class by `MovieClip(root).addChild(spawn1);`. In my minions class I've put the code for them to fall and stop upon hitting the ground and also follow my character.

I have a VCam(virtual camera) movieClip to follow my character(who moves on the stage, not the stage around him) with this code build-in:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

//VCam
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);
function handleEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    if (parent) {
        parent.scaleX = 1 / scaleX;
        parent.scaleY = 1 / scaleY;

        if (rotation == 0) {
            parent.x = (width / 2 - x) / scaleX;
            parent.y = (height / 2 - y) / scaleY;
            parent.rotation = 0;
        } else {
            var bounds:Rectangle = getBounds(this);
            var angle:Number = rotation * Math.PI / 180;

            var midX:Number = -x / scaleX;
            var midY:Number = -y / scaleY;
            var rx:Number = -bounds.width / 2;
            var ry:Number = -bounds.height / 2;

            var cos:Number = Math.cos(angle);
            var sin:Number = Math.sin(angle);
            var rotatedX:Number = rx * cos - ry * sin;
            var rotatedY:Number = ry * cos + rx * sin;
            var cornerX:Number = midX - rotatedX;
            var cornerY:Number = midY - rotatedY;

            cos = Math.cos(-angle);
            sin = Math.sin(-angle);
            parent.x = cornerX * cos - cornerY * sin;
            parent.y = cornerY * cos + cornerX * sin;

            parent.rotation = -rotation;
        }
    }
}

addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, handleRemoved, false, 0, true);
function handleRemoved(event:Event):void 
    {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);
    removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, handleRemoved);
    }
```

When I jump with my character it seems that the minions follow the movement of my vcam and not behaving normally, jumping with the camera and falling throu'the ground when the character falls.

If I add a child normally from the main timeline by `addChild(m_clip);` it does not behave like that.

Is there an easy fix? Thanks!

This is the minions class code:

```
    package  {

        import flash.display.*;
        import flash.events.*;


        public class EnemySpawned extends MovieClip {

            protected var gravitysp: Number = 1;
            protected var ySpeedsp: Number = 0;
            protected var Speedsp: Number = 6.5;
            var charMTL:MovieClip;

            public function EnemySpawned() 
            {
                this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movement);
                trace('exist');
            }
            function movement(event:Event):void
            {
                var MTL:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);
                charMTL = MTL.char1;

                ySpeedsp += gravitysp;
                if(! MTL.ground_1.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y, true))
                {
                    this.y += ySpeedsp;
                }
                if(ySpeedsp > 40)
                    {
                        ySpeedsp = 40;
                    }
                for(var j:int = 0; j<20; j++)
                    {
                        if(MTL.ground_1.hitTestPoint(this.x, this.y, true))
                            {
                                this.y--
                                ySpeedsp = 0;
                        }
                }

            var Distance:Number = charMTL.x - this.x;
            if(Distance < -charMTL.width/2 - this.width/2)
            {
                this.x -= Speedsp;
            }
            if(Distance > charMTL.width/2 + this.width/2)
            {
                this.x += Speedsp;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

There is no moving of `ground_1` movieClip via code.

Comment: Try `player.parent.addChild(spawn1)`. As I understand your question, you want your "minions" to move around the unaltered stage, and be affected by VCam's transformation, as they are independent of the player, while they follow him. So, the proper way of handling this will be making the new minion a child of the VCam, or at least the world that should be a child (or a sub-child) of the VCam, in terms of display list

Comment: This resulted in the same behavior. I want my "minions" to not be affected by vcam's transformation. As I can see (the vcam code not being mine) the vcam alters its 'parent', that being the stage. I want my "minions" to move around the stage unaffected by the vcam. Sorry if I've explained it poorly.

Comment: Not sure about your other class that adds the minions, but this sounds like a root v/s parent issue.  Take a look at this other question and see if it fixes your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589904/moviecliproot-not-working-how-to-access-root-variable-from-movieclip-flash-a

Comment: MainTimeline(parent) does not work. it isn't recognized. "access of undefined property". I've tried putting it in a var, that didn't work.

Comment: If I trace(this); or trace(MovieClip(root)); from the maintimeline I get [object MainTimeline]. Same goes if i trace(MovieClip(root)) from my class. So MovieClip(root).addChild(whatever) shouldn't work the same as addChild from the maintimeline code?

Comment: ok so first I would look at the code that actually adds the minions and see exactly where in the display list they are because the code for the VCam is manipulating it's parent... so maybe see if the VCams parent and the display object containing the minions (or minions parent etc) are the same at run-time.  If so, you can change that to prevent the cam from moving the minions by moving the minions out of that display hierarchy.